# Get a document with a specific field value in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I want to check if a document with a specific email exists.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a view that has email as a key and query that view for the specific email address. Which values are appropriate for the view depends on what you're going to do with the results. You may, for example, choose the number of documents containing an email address as the values of the view.

This is a short introduction to views:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views

Comment: this link is broken

Answer (score 3):

The release 2.0.0 of CouchDB already provides a simple JSON-based way to perform CouchDB queries without MapReduce. Further details are available in the [_find, _index and _explain API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/find.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea for a `map`-function in your view (`_design/foo`):

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.email) {
        emit(doc.email, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: no, this will simply give a list of all docs that have any email -- not what was asked -- you would need to emit(doc.email,doc._id), then query the view with "?key=email"